# shorten large 14+ digit numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, base64

i'm using a weird proprietary scripting language for a project. 
i need to provide a user with a large (14+ digit) number, which they will have to reenter into another system (for later data correlation). having a user enter a number that large (by hand) with no errors will be almost impossible, and will undoubtedly disenfranchise users.

i have been trying to come up with a solution to shorten that number using base64, but all the code i have found is way to complex for this scripting language. is there a simple math algorithm (lossless compression) i can use to make a large number smaller? the result being alpha numeric is fine.

Comment: You cannot compress arbitrary data. Unless the data has some kind of pattern, lossless compression is impossible in principle.

Comment: Is there a maximum number you'll need to support?

Comment: if anything, base64 will INCREASE the size of a string by around 33%. is this 14digit number actually encoded as a human-readable string? 14digits would EASILY fit within a 64bit integer if converted to a binary representation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No, this is "compressing" by changing the base of symbols required. For example, it's trivial to "compress" an 8-bit binary number into two hex digits. That's the sort of thing the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MarcB: Your comment about base64 would be appropriate if the OP were suggesting treating each digit as a separate byte. I don't believe that's the intention here at all.

Comment: @MarcB: Really? The base 10 number `3,684,870,736,632,296,809` base64 encodes to `aTUzZGlKIzM=`.

Comment: i dont want to go into too much detail, but there is a simple pattern. the first 4 digits are 2 identifiers each from 00-99 and the other 10 digits are an epoch time.

Comment: Natively, is this really a number?  Or is it simply a string composed solely of numeric characters?

Comment: Entering 14 lowercase letters might be easier than entering 14 numbers, especially when those letters resemble words (mix of wowels, consonants)

Comment: @david: only if tht number was stored in a binary format to begin with. if it's a string format (25 chars), the b64 encoding is `Myw2ODQsODcwLDczNiw2MzIsMjk2LDgwOQ==` (36 chars).

Comment: @MarcB: A number cannot be a string format. String formats hold representations of numbers, not numbers. I'm not sure how you made this about strings. Nobody is talking about strings but you. We're talking about *numbers*. A strings of base 10 digits encoded in ASCII is certainly one way to represent a number, but we're talking about pure numbers here. The question never mentions strings and is clear that it's talking about a number. How the number is encoded is irrelevant provided it's the number itself you convert to Base64.

Comment: If you can convert that 14-digit number (I assume you can treat it as a number rather than as a string) to a hex representation, it's only 12 characters. If you present it to the user in 4-character groups (i.e. 0B3A-73CE-531A), it will be much easier for them to enter without error.

Comment: Typing letters mixed with numbers is bloody uncomfortable, especially when letters must be uppercase.

Comment: So make the letters lowercase. Or, use A-P as the "hex digits". So the number would be something like ALCJ-GCMO-ECBJ. The script can handle the conversion of that to/from hex.

Comment: i like the delimitation idea. i think that will increase accuracy. but there is no built in number2hex code in the language. is there a simple math equation for that?

Comment: Quick JavaScript example: http://jsfiddle.net/fTwWX/

Comment: It's perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/fTwWX/8/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanx for the great discussion everone.
i ended up implementing a combination of many of your suggestions.

i ended used encoding it in base36 (hexatridecimal) and delimited the string into smaller blocks.

biziclop - if you has submitted an answer as opposed to a comment i would have accepted it. your js code got me thinking in the right direction... thanx!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have more of a UX problem than a math problem. Why not split the number to be memorized in 2. The average person is capable of memorizing and reciting 7 digits with their short-term memory. Granted, it is based on old research & depends on age and mental capacity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two

Comment: Considering the numbers you need to enter for things like XBox Live accounts when you buy a card from the store, 14+ digits is short and simple.  I think splitting it into smaller bits like you suggest would be more than sufficient